# Changing service order using Terminal

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, system-settings

I would like to write a script to change the service order from Ethernet 1 to Ethernet 2.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `networksetup` to do this:

```
networksetup -ordernetworkservices <service1> <service2> <service3> <...>
```

For full details, refer to the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) (`man networksetup`)

Comment: So it would be:

networksetup -ordernetworkservices Ethernet_2 Ethernet_1

for one, then changing back would be 

networksetup -ordernetworkservices Ethernet_1 Ethernet_2

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct.  Assuming you want to put Ethernet 2 as priority over Ethernet 1 and then change them back.  I suggest putting the services in quotes to handle the spaces.

Comment: You're my hero allan, thank you.  I'll try to work that out and get back to this :)

Comment: Allan, I messed around with it a little bit.  Changed the names to make it easier.  Using networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Public" "Ethernet" "Wi-fi" so that I'm on my outside internet, and networksetup -ordernetworkservices "Ethernet" "Public" "Wi-fi" to get back to my work ethernet.